# Some say I killed my brother

Tags: cryptic-clues, history

I was godless yet I warred with God.

Some say I killed my brother,

Inside he bled a lot. [see hint 2]

Generally I had a tough reputation.

Yet to modern ears I can sound quite sweet!

---

Who was I and can you explain each line of my description?

---

Hint 1

> "I" was a well-known *historical* person, hence the **history** tag.
>  So, I'm disallowing purely mythical figures, although "I" was and am
>  certainly legendary.

Hint 2

> The clue "... my brother; inside he bled a lot." uses a common cryptic-clue technique.
>
> Note for cryptic solvers.
>
> I did not say "... my brother: twisted inside he bled a lot", instead I said, "... my brother - inside he bled a lot."  This excludes "Abel"!
>
> For people who are not used to cryptic crosswords, don't worry, all will become clear when you solve the rest of it.

Hint3

> The sweetness aspect will perhaps be most familiar to US speakers of English although, speaking as a Brit, I'm sure people from the UK are familiar with the term from movies and TV.

Comment: Are you sure [cryptic-clues] is a good tag here? It means you have a cryptic crossword clue in the post.

Comment: @bobble - I have one definite cryptic-crossword type clue and another that most people would probably think qualifies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve been thinking about this for a while, and I’m stuck on

> Attila the Hun

I was godless yet I warred with God.

> Attila was a Hun — a Godless barbarian — yet was nicknamed “the Scourge of God”

Some say I killed my brother,

> His brother, another famous Hunnic leader, died on a suspicious hunting trip and was thought by many to be killed by Attila

Inside he bled a lot.

> His brother’s name was inside “he **bled a** lot”, namely, *Bleda* the Hun.

Generally I had a tough reputation.

> Attila did indeed have a tough reputation; and as noticed by @user70451, he was also the General of the Hunnic Armies.

Yet to modern ears I can sound quite sweet!

> ‘Hun’ is a term of endearment, especially in the US (and sometimes Canada too!). Hun is also short for honey which is definitely sweet!

Comment: Congratulations - You have found me! There is one subtle point you have missed (the last-but-one clue) and one not-so-subtle (the final one).

Comment: I think I got the not so subtle point, now...

Comment: You have certainly improved the final clue's answer. One more step is possible - rot13(Jul vf "uha" pbafvqrerq fjrrg?).  Last-but-one, is the subtle one. Read every word of the clue carefully. rot13(rfcrpvnyyl gur svefg jbeq!)

Comment: He was a rot13(trareny) or at least a rot13(yrnqre)

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica — I can’t seem to find the second quasi-cryptic you were referencing in the comments above, although I feel like that has something to do with it....

Comment: rot13("Trarenyyl" and "fbhaq dhvgr fjrrg") are kind of cryptic IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I'll bite and write the naive answer which is probably wrong and intended as a distraction from the real one...

> You are Cain.

I was godless yet I warred with God

> You did a thing which people would classify as godless: murdered your brother. Then you had a verbal argument with God.

In general I had a bad reputation

> You are the first murderer in the judeo-christian mythology. Also, you are a homonym for "cane", which was used to discipline children in the past - painfully so

to modern ears I can sound quite sweet

> To continiue with the "cane" homonym, modern people frequently associate it with sugar cane, which became a widespread sweetener in the industrial era

Comment: Yes, I deliberately baited the hook. Hadn't thought of the "cane" connection so +1 for that. Not my answer though.

Comment: P.S. One quibble, *"Some say I killed my brother"*. I think *everyone* thinks your person killed their brother. In this case it is not so certain.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica about your quibble, not all the world population, and not even all Christians, regard the biblical stories as having truly happened.

Comment: @rumtscho - good point! How about my hint? I think I might have got you there (?) (Although you'll notice it's a close thing)

Answer (score 3):

I pretty sure the answer is

> Arjuna -- [Arjuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjuna) is a protagonist of the Indian epic Mahabharata and also appears in other ancient Hindu mythological texts.

I was godless yet I warred with God.

> Arjuna had a fight with a Hindu god, [lord shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva), also known as "the great god".

Some say I killed my brother;

> Arjuna fought this war, but was not aware that he was fighting his brother. Karna (Arjuna's brother) *was* aware that Arjuna was his brother, but still chose to fight him. The result was that Karna got killed.

inside he bled a lot.

> Arjuna felt very sorry for killing his own brother.

In general I had a bad reputation

> Arjuna is known to be stubborn and is overly proud of how he comports himself and his reputation.

yet to modern ears I can sound quite sweet!

> [Arjuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminalia_arjuna) is a sweet kind of fruit.

Comment: Another ingenious answer! (+1) However, if you read carefully, it says "*I* killed *my* brother; inside *he* bled a lot."* You can see that "he" refers to the brother. Note also the hidden hint that indicates what type of clue that sentence is. Another point is that I think you are saying Arjuna is a fictional character - mine is historical (and very well-known)  - see the history tag. However, the "sweet" part fits very well (perhaps better in some respects than my answer!)